# How to "filter" duplicate item in select statement

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables : "`Hotels`" and "`Area`".

"`Hotels`" table has the following columns: `INDEX, NAME, AREA`

Sample data :

```
(1,'hotel bla", 4)
```

"`Area`" tbale has the following columns: `INDEX, NAME, CODE`

Sample data :

```
(4,'TEL-AVIV','TLV')
```

This means the "`hotel bla`" is in `tel aviv`

I need to create a list of hotels that have the same name and area ("duplicate hotels")
for examaple:
Hotels has 3 recoreds:

```
1,'hotel a',1
2,'hotel a',1
3,'hotel b',2
4,'hotel b',2
5,'hotel c',1
```

Area has 2 records

```
1,'tel-aviv','TLV'
2,'haifa','HAF'
```

The output should be something like:
    'hotel a','1'
    'hotel b,'2'

update:
If I have only 1 record of the hotel in the table I don't want to return it.
All your answer will also return it

see the fixed examaple

Comment: So you don't need your `Area` table ?

Comment: @Brewal - i don't need it. it was just for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the distinct keyword to get only distinct records.

```
select distinct name, area from hotels
```

This would give you only unique rows if you only need name and area columns.

But if you need the ID column as well you can try

```
select id, max(name) name, max(area) as area from hotels group by name,area;
```

or

```
select id, first(name) name, first(area) as area from hotels group by name,area;
```

depending on what DBMS you're using

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, area
  from hotels
 group by name, area
having count(1) > 1;
```

This will give you hotels having same name and belonging to same area.

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8319f/1).

Comment: Shouldn't it be COUNT(*) ?

Comment: @Fred, both will return same value.